# How do Spring's security annotations on methods work?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-security, authorization

Consider this code:

```
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class SecureStuff {
    @PreAuthorize("#user.password == #oldPassword")
    public static void changePassword(User user, String oldPassword, String newPassword){
       System.out.print("Changing passwords ...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User joe = new User("Joe", "HansWurst", true, true, true, true, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        changePassword(joe, "HansWurst", "TeeWurst");
    }

}
```

I ran the code in STS (SpringSource Tool Suite) and it worked as expected. (It printed `"Changing passwords ..."`.)
Then I renamed the password to something else, expecting the method call to fail now.

I have already added the line `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` to my `applicationContext-security.xml` configuration file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. These annotations don't work on `static` methods
2. To make these annotations work you need to declare your object as a bean of the application context (the one with `<global-method-security>` element), and call the annotated method on the instance obtained from the context.

Basically, these annotations are based on Spring AOP support and inherit all limitations of a [proxy-based AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). For better understanding you can take a look at the [Spring AOP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction).

Comment: Interesting, care to explain a bit more in detail?

Answer (score 1):

@PreAuthorize does work on static methods, but you need to set the mode of global-method-security to aspectj

```
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" mode="aspectj"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't find any documentation on this and adding mode="aspectj" breaks @PreAuthorize on non-static methods for me.